# Derivation of Strehl ratio

Tags: fourier-transform, transfer-function, impulse-response, parseval

I am in trouble proving the following fact:

The Strehl ratio is the ratio of the volume of the aberrated OTF (optical transfer function) and the ideal OTF, i.e.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}=\frac{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y}{\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{H}_{dl}(f_x, f_y) df_x df_y} \tag{1}\label{eq:goal}
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{H}$ is the aberrated OTF and $\mathcal{H}_{dl}$ is the ideal OTF.

---

**My attempt:**

The Strehl ratio is defined as the ratio of the on-axis actual PSF (point spread function) value to the on-axis ideal PSF value.

- What is PSF with aberration (=actual PSF)?

  The PSF is the impulse response of a spatially incoherent imaging system, and it can be computed as the squared magnitude of the amplitude spread function, $h(u,v)$:
  \begin{align}
  \text{PSF}(u,v) &= |h(u,v)|^2 \\
  &= \left|\frac{1}{\lambda z}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(x,y)e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{\lambda z}(ux+vy)}dx dy \right|^2 \\
  &= \left|\frac{1}{\lambda z} \mathcal{F}\{\mathcal{P}(x,y)\}_{f_x=\frac{u}{\lambda z}, f_y=\frac{v}{\lambda z}} \right|^2 \tag{2}\label{eq:PSF}
  \end{align}
  where $\lambda$ is a wavelength, $z$ is a propagation distance, $(u,v)$ is an coordinate on an imaging plane, and $\mathcal{P}(x,y)$ is a generaized pupil function that considers an aberration:
  \begin{align}
  \mathcal{P}(x,y)=P(x,y)e^{j \phi(x,y)} \tag{3}\label{eq:gen_pupil}
  \end{align}
  where $P(x,y)$ is a pupil function and $\phi(x,y)$ is the optical phase.

  Thus, the on-axis PSF with aberration is
  \begin{align}
  \text{PSF}(0,0) &=  \left|\frac{1}{\lambda z}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(x,y)e^{0}dx dy \right|^2 \\
  &= \frac{1}{\lambda^2 z^2}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(x,y) dx dy \right|^2 \tag{4}\label{eq:PSF_onaxis}
  \end{align}
- What is PSF without aberration (=ideal PSF)?

  We can simply replace the generalized pupil function with the pupil function in the PSF we obtained earlier. Thus, the on-axis ideal PSF value is
  \begin{align}
  \text{PSF}_{dl}(0,0) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2 z^2}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y) dx dy \right|^2 \tag{5}\label{eq:PSF_dl_onaxis}
  \end{align}
- Strehl ratio directly obtained from its definition

  Based on the definition and \eqref{eq:PSF_onaxis} and \eqref{eq:PSF_dl_onaxis}, the Strehl ratio is
  \begin{align}
     \mathcal{S} = \frac{\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(x,y) dx dy \right|^2}{\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(x,y) dx dy \right|^2} \tag{6}\label{eq:S1}
  \end{align}
  but this is still expressed in terms of the pupil functions. In order to derive \eqref{eq:goal}, we need to consider the relationship between the OTF and the pupil functions.
- Relationship between $\mathcal{H}(f_x,f_y)$ and $\mathcal{P}(x,y)$

  The OTF, i.e. $\mathcal{H}(f_x,f_y)$ can be expressed in terms of the PSF like below:
  \begin{align}
     \mathcal{H}(f_x, f_y) = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{|h(u,v)|^2 \}}
  {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(u,v)|^2 du \ dv} 
  = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{\text{PSF}(u,v) \}}
  {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{PSF}(u,v) du \ dv} \tag{7}\label{eq:OTF}
     \end{align}

---

This is where I got stuck. Any idea how to derive \eqref{eq:goal} from \eqref{eq:S1} and \eqref{eq:OTF}? It seems like I need to use [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) but I am not sure how to apply it.